# Parquet file load into snowflake table - cast element values to target column data type Issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, snowflake-schema

I have a table of data type VARIANT that holds a parquet file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmR4R.png)
I have a relational table of the format.

```
create table xx.PUBLIC.social_test(
WEB_ID NUMBER(38,0), 
WEB_NAME VARCHAR(128), 
PARENT_ID NUMBER(38,0), 
DEPTH NUMBER(18,0), 
HIERARCHY_ID NUMBER(19,0),
LEVEL_ID NUMBER(19,0),
MMXMP_UV NUMBER(20,6), 
FB_UV NUMBER(20,6),
IG_UV NUMBER(20,6),  
TW_UV NUMBER(20,6),  
Social NUMBER(20,6), 
Total NUMBER(20,6)
);
```

Because all Parquet data is stored in a single column, I want to cast element values to the target column data type.

```
create or replace table xx.PUBLIC.social_test AS
Select
$1:depth::NUMBER , 
$1:fb_uv::NUMBER , 
$1:hierarchy_id::NUMBER , 
$1:ig_uv::NUMBER , 
$1:level_id::NUMBER , 
$1:mmxmp_uv::NUMBER , 
$1:parent_id::NUMBER , 
$1:social::NUMBER , 
$1:total::NUMBER , 
$1:tw_uv::NUMBER , 
$1:web_id::NUMBER , 
$1:web_name::VARCHAR
from xx.PUBLIC.social_parquet;
```

Why this query didn't work , and show an error: Missing column specification. How to cast element values to the target column data type.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: I would start by expliticly listing the target column names in your CREATE TABLE … AS statement and make sure they align with the columns in the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're showing in your question is due to not providing names for the columns in your new table.

This should at least get you past that error

```sql
  create or replace table xx.PUBLIC.social_test AS
  Select
    $1:depth::NUMBER as DEPTH, 
    $1:fb_uv::NUMBER as FB_UV, 
    $1:hierarchy_id::NUMBER as HIERARCHY_ID, 
    $1:ig_uv::NUMBER as IG_UV, 
    $1:level_id::NUMBER as LEVEL_ID, 
    $1:mmxmp_uv::NUMBER as MMXMP_UV, 
    $1:parent_id::NUMBER as PARENT_ID, 
    $1:social::NUMBER as SOCIAL, 
    $1:total::NUMBER as TOTAL, 
    $1:tw_uv::NUMBER as TW_UV, 
    $1:web_id::NUMBER as WEB_ID, 
    $1:web_name::VARCHAR as WEB_NAME
  from xx.PUBLIC.social_parquet;
```

I don't see any other obvious data type issues from your script and screenshot. If you do get new errors, then it will help if you can include a full sample record, in text, that is giving the error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything works properly after adding the column name.

Comment: glad I could help :)  
Don't forget to accept a response as a best answer when a question addresses your issue well.